# Get values from Javascript object in Rails controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm fairly new to Rails but I have a situation where a user can create a vacancy and select modules for that vacancy by dragging en dropping modules.
Everytime something has changed (a module has been added/removes to the vacancy of the order has changed) I send a javascript object to the rails controller through AJAX and I want to extract the values from this object and story them in my DB.

My object will look like this:

```
addedModules = {
   module: [
      {module_id: '1', name: 'first-module', width: '3', height: '1', position: '1'},
      {module_id: '5', name: 'fifth-module', width: '1', height: '1', position: '2'},
      {module_id: '3', name: 'third-module', width: '4', height: '1', position: '3'},
   ]
};
```

In my controller I would like to go through every module and extract their module_id, name, etc.

AJAX block:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../../../vacancies/" + <%= params[:vacancy_id] %> + "/update_with_modules",
    data: "addedModules=" + addedModules
}).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Is there a way to do so or is there a better solution?

Comment: Do you find your object in the params?

Comment: I get the object using `params[:addedModules]`, but if I use `params[:addedModules][0]` or something like that I get "[" and with `params[:addedModules][1]` I get "o" so it's getting the word "object" and not the values of the object.

Comment: try params[:addedModules][:module][0]

Comment: I get an Internal Server Error back from AJAX

Comment: Can you show me the logs of this error?

Comment: I just tested your code, it works with params[:addedModules][:module][0]

Comment: `Parameters: {"order"=>"[object Object]", "vacancy_id"=>"15"}

 User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 8], ["LIMIT", 1]]

Vacancy Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "vacancies".* FROM "vacancies" WHERE "vacancies"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 15], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)


  
TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer):
  
app/controllers/vacancies_controller.rb:68:in `[]'
app/controllers/vacancies_controller.rb:68:in `update_with_modules'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133814/discussion-between-othmane-el-kesri-and-bramh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
data: "addedModules=" + addedModules
```

by this line:

```
data: {addedModules: addedModules}
```